# iphone app submission for iOS 6.0

Tags: xcode, store, submission

I have existing iphone app which is developed using XCode 4.2 and base sdk as iOS 5.0,Compiler is APPLE LLVM compiler 3.0.
Now as the iOS 6 is upcoming am I supposed to (or rather ought to) rebuild this app with latest XCode and the base SDK (i.e. XCode 4.5, base sdk as iOS 6.0, Compiler :-Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1) or will I be OK submitting my upgrade with older XCode and base SDK settings?
Will I be facing any issue while submitting my app built with older settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your app works fine with iOS5 and you don't need any futures from iOS6, then leave it like this. iOS6 suppose to support the apps build with previous iOS. So, it means your app should work.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. Apple in such case would not mandate to bundle the application with SDK 6.0 which is officially getting released along with iOS 6.0 ?

Comment: of cause not. At moment I'm cleaning up my third app which is build on iOS5 and my two preceding apps are build on iOS4. I will not even bother myself to reconstruct them for iOS6.

Comment: If you made them with previous iOS version, then you have to submit them so.